# Including template PHP file at the end of functions file

Tags: php

I'm learning basic PHP with a book. Inside the book I have done this example:

```
<?php
session_start()

if(array_key_exists("taskName", $_GET)) {
    $_SESSION["taskList"][] = $_GET["taskName"];
}

$taskList= [];

if(array_key_exists("taskList", $_SESSION)) {
    $taskList = $_SESSION["taskList"];
}

include "template.php";
```

The "include template.php" at the end of "functions.php" file is used in the book and it seems to work. But, when using in my example, the template.php which is used to be displayed the results, didn't work, here are the template.php part which uses PHP code:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Tasks</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach($taskList as $task) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$task?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
```

Here are displayed errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: taskList in C:\xampp\htdocs\to-do-list\template.php on line 27

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\to-do-list\template.php on line 27
```

In my understanding, the template.php isn't getting info from functions.php as the book it gets.

[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

In this documentation above have the following example:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
include 'b.inc';
?>
```

So, b.inc will have the $a var. It's the same what happens in the book.

Comment: And the question you want to ask is ... what?

Comment: Have you include functions.php or template.php in your code? also dont think `<?=$task?>` is a valid statement, also it's not a good idea to mix long php tag with the short one ie `<?php ?>`, and `<? ?>`.

Comment: Do you access the main file or template.php in your browser? Looks like the latter. There's no ay the included file would lose the variables defined in the parent file.

Comment: @MaxZoom actually I'm trying to understand why isn't working, as the book (I think is correct) and works.

Comment: @ryo7689 `<?=$task?>` is perfectly valid is you enable `short_tags` in the PHP config.

Comment: @ryo7689 thanks, I'll change this. I've included "template.php" inside "functions.php" at the end. Template.php is used as "index.php" in this example.

Comment: @Capsule I'm accessing the template.php in my browser (used like index.php in this example). And include in the last line of functions.php

Comment: Include `functions.php` in `index.php` and access `index.php` in your browser. If you access `template.php` of course it doesn't have the variables that are supposed to be defined in `functions.php`

Comment: Missing semicolon at the end of `session_start()`, not your overall issue here though.

Comment: @Enstage fixed that, thanks.

Comment: @Capsule yes, that way the error disappeared. But, just for understanding purpose, in the book he included at the end of functions and seems to work. Or maybe the book is incorrect, lol

Comment: @Capsule edited the question with PHP doc example.

Comment: @RodrigoSchneiderWernke please quote the book for clarification. They either include the functions in the index, or directly access the function file in the browser, but there's no way it can work by accessing the template directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried below code it works fine on my computer (it produces some output).

File: first.php

```
<?php
$taskList = [];
$taskList[]=5;
$taskList[]=6;
include 'second.php';
?>
```

File: second.php

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Tasks</th>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($taskList as $task) : ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?=$task?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: hi, edited the question to describe best my problem. I think isn't a problem with short tags.

Comment: Pls let me know if that works for you: `php first.php`

Comment: Hi @MaxZoom yes it helped me a lot to understand what I've done wrong. In the book they access the "second" and the "first" which is my template is used just to display results.

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

Your example works just fine, however since I can't think to start where is the problem exactly, I'd suggest to

- Edit `session_start()` line to add semicolon at the end of the line.
- Make sure to open the url of functions.php file not the template.php file.
- If this error applies when you request the file functions.php without GET arguments then try to provide an argument. like http://localhost/test/functions.php?taskName=anyName.

Here is the exact code I tried and called the functions.php with and without arguments and works fine

**functions.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if(array_key_exists("taskName", $_GET)) {
    $_SESSION["taskList"][] = $_GET["taskName"];
}

$taskList= [];

if(array_key_exists("taskList", $_SESSION)) {
    $taskList = $_SESSION["taskList"];
}

include "template.php";
```

**template.php**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Tasks</th>
    </tr>
        <?php foreach($taskList as $task) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$task?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```